# when using smack and servlets to connect to facebook chat

Tags: java, facebook, servlets, chat, smack

using jar files: `smack3.3.1.jar`, `restfb 1.5.4.jar`

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet FriendsListServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2398)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2708)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:328)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:806)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem with myeclipse, I have removed all jar files from myproject(right-click)>>properties>>java Built Path>> libraries.
Then I added jar files directly to lib folder of myproject.
It solved my problem.